# help installation samsung xpress m2022

Tags: printing

First of all I'm sorry if my English could be not the best, it's not my mother tongue.
I've seen that printer was a pain for a lot of user, and I've wasted even too much time in searching solutions, and try everything, so I have to beg for mercy and need a step-by-step help.
I think a driver is installed (or maybe installed several times: I used the cd with wine, then the terminal, then etc, I don't even remember!), I don't know, maybe you can tell me what command should I type to see it.
The printer is new, so I hope it's ok, but nevertheless when I press the button on it it works and prints a sheet.
But when I try to print it says it's impossible to localize the printer...

Comment: How is your printer connected to your computer? `sudo lspci` or `lsusb` should show it. Does the printer show up in `dmesg -T`?